# Checkbox checked data save to database

Tags: php, jquery, html, pdo

**Problem:** when a checkbox is checked to corresponding ***radnummer*** will be updated in the database with the value from the ***input*** (see below). But nothing happens. Nothing is updated. I want to save the value from the input when the checkbox is checked. (Confusing enough?). :)

**Question:** how do I check which checkboxes that is checked?

Please feel free to use my code below or any chosen example.

```
foreach ($_POST['K'] as $radnummer => $value) {

    // Anything saved?                          
    $finns_det_iup = $iup->finns_det_radnummer_iup($_GET['amne_id'], $radnummer, $_GET['elev_id']); 

    // Send to IUP
    if (isset($_POST['IUP'][$radnummer])){

        $amne_id = $_POST['amne_id'];
        $eleven = $_GET['elev_id'];

        // INSERT
        if ($finns_det_iup == false){

        try{            
            $iup_nytt_klick  = $db->prepare("

            INSERT INTO `iup_kunskapskrav_klick` 
            (amne_id, radnummer, elev_id, lid, kunsk_klick, datum) 
            VALUES (:amne_id, :radnummer, :elev_id, :lid, :kunsk_klicket, :datum) 

            ");                     

            $iup_nytt_klick->bindParam(':amne_id', $amne_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $iup_nytt_klick->bindParam(':radnummer', $radnummer, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $iup_nytt_klick->bindParam(':elev_id', $eleven, PDO::PARAM_INT);                    
            $iup_nytt_klick->bindParam(':lid', $lid, PDO::PARAM_INT);                               
            $iup_nytt_klick->bindParam(':kunsk_klicket', $value[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);            
            $iup_nytt_klick->bindParam(':datum', $datum, PDO::PARAM_STR);                                               

            $iup_nytt_klick->execute();

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }       

        } else {

            // UPDATE
            $ny_lid = $_SESSION['lid'];     
            $eleven = $_GET['elev_id']; 
            $amne_id = $_POST['amne_id'];   

            try{            
                $iup_uppdatera_klick  = $db->prepare("
                UPDATE `iup_kunskapskrav_klick` 
                SET `kunsk_klick`=:kunsk_klicket,
                    `datum`=:datum, 
                    `lid`=:lid                                      
                WHERE `amne_id`=:amne_id AND `elev_id`=:elev_id AND `radnummer`=:radnummer ");                          

                $iup_uppdatera_klick->bindParam(':datum', $datum, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $iup_uppdatera_klick->bindParam(':lid', $ny_lid, PDO::PARAM_INT);                   
                $iup_uppdatera_klick->bindParam(':kunsk_klicket', $value[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
                $iup_uppdatera_klick->bindParam(':amne_id', $amnet, PDO::PARAM_STR);    
                $iup_uppdatera_klick->bindParam(':elev_id', $eleven, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $iup_uppdatera_klick->bindParam(':radnummer', $radnummer, PDO::PARAM_INT);                                          

                $iup_uppdatera_klick->execute();

            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }   

        }

    } // END 1
} // END 2
```

**The checkbox**

```
<td class="info" rowspan="5">                                          
   <input type="checkbox" name="IUP[<?php echo $kk['radnummer'];?>]" value="<?php echo $kk['radnummer'];?>"><i></i>
</td>
```

**The input**

```
<th>                 
    <input class="abb_table_center" type="radio" value ="<?php echo $kk['kunskapstyp']; ?>" name="K[<?php echo $kk['radnummer'];?>][]" <?php if ($kk['kunskapstyp'] == $hamta_klicken['abb_klicket']) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>><i class="rounded-x"></i>                                            
</th>
```

Comment: `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')` returns all checked checkboxes. Same for radios if you change type="checkbox" to type="radio"...

Comment: `nothing happens` ..other than a form submit ( not shown ) what is expected to happen? Update on each click using javascript? Overall issue is not clear. If it is a server side problem with submit please specify and do a dump of the request to check what it contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Ted mentioned, you can grab all of the checkboxes that are checked by using this selector 'input[type="checkbox"]:checked'. I would also attach data to the checkbox containing the radnummer field so you can find the input relating to the checkbox. Here is an example of this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="IUP[<?php echo $kk['radnummer'];?>]" data-radnummer="<?php echo $kk['radnummer'];?>" value="<?php echo $kk['radnummer'];?>"><i></i>
```

Once the data is attached to the checkbox you can loop over the available checkboxes and grab the data from the inputs based on the radnummer

```
$.each($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'), function (i, key) {
    var radnummer = $(key).data('radnummer');
    //find input based on radnummer retrieved
    textboxValue = $('#K[' + radnummer + '][]').val()
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually POST of a checkbox is "on" you need validate if is "on" or of, but if you need the value then you need use javascript AJAX.